# Crookes radiometer showing radiation pressure

Tags: classical-mechanics, visible-light, experimental-physics

Originally, the Crookes radiometer was meant to measure the light intensity. For decades the explanation for its rotation was debated. It is now known that the rotation does not originate from radiation pressure, but from a pressure difference arising because of differential heating and imperfect vacuum.

Is it possible (or was it done), to build a Crookes radiometer with a vacuum good enough to show radiation pressure? Therefore rotating in the opposite direction than usual. Or are there other limitations such as typical amount of friction? How would you estimate the vacuum required to have a radiation pressure force dominating the one from heating?

Comment: Wikipedia - "At these very high vacuums the effect of photon radiation pressure on the vanes can be observed in very sensitive apparatus (see [Nichols radiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichols_radiometer)) but this is insufficient to cause rotation."

Comment: @Farcher thank you for your relevant comment. I have also seen that sentence. I was wandering if more quantitative statements can be made.

Comment: I thnk that the radiation pressure is so small that a Crookes' vane type apparatus will never rotate but will suffer a deflection as per Nichols & Hull . I have found [this article](https://www.sciencealert.com/photon-momentum-radiation-pressure-measured-light-matter-interaction) which may be of interest?